# Other ways besides push to wake up an iOS app?

Tags: ios, push

Has anyone created an iOS app reacts to events or triggers from external sources other than push (APNS)? For example, could an iOS app subscribe to a remote topic or queue? Or listen for HTTP or socket requests?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what you are aiming to build? More concrete information will aid finding possible answers or workarounds.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Application could be launched if:

1. User tapped the icon
2. User selected the Push-notification/Local-notification
3. Application supports url-schemes and is launched while opening URL
4. Application supports view/edit of documents and user've selected your app to do this

If anyone has other ideas - feel free to edit or add comments.

App could run in background and have active http-connection/socket. But it couldn't be opened automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to user action and push/local notifications, an app can be woken by a significant location change, if the app has indicated that it wants to monitor such events.

See: [CLLocationManager Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges)

Look for a method called `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`. If a significant location change occurs while your app is not in the foreground or isn't running at all, your application will be launched in the background, allowing the app to perform background-only operations (e.g. no view code will run).

The app will not launch into the foreground, however, if it is launched due to a significant location change.